# PHP transaction handling with multiple mysqli object

Tags: php, database, transactions, mysqli

Lets put the case that we've got two separate classes, each owns a `mysqli` object to use for database operations.

```
class A{
  protected $mysqliObject;
  public function __constructor(){
    $this->mysqliObject=new mysqli(...)
  }
  public function doSomething(){
    $this->mysqliObject->query(...);
  }
}
class B{
  protected $mysqliObject;
  public function __constructor(){
    $this->mysqliObject=new mysqli(...)
  }
  public function doSomething(){
    $this->mysqliObject->query(...);
  }
}
```

The `doSomething()` methods use the `$mysqliObject` for a database query (SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, etc...). I want to do the following outside:

```
// Start point
$aObject=new A();
$bObject=new B();
$aObject->doSomething();
$bObject->doSomething();
// End point
```

...but I want to roll back both queries if any of them fails. How can I do that?

- Can I create a brand new `mysqli` object at "Start point", and use it to commit or rollback at "End point" the database query of `class A` and `class B`?
- Do I have to create outside, and pass the same `$mysqliObject` to the `__constructor()` of `class A` and `class B`, and use that to rollback or commit (outside).

Would like to see more techniques with pro-con's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each database connection object you have represents a different connection to the database, even if the connection is to the same database server.  Each connection is completely independent of each other, so a transaction started in one connection will be invisible to the other connection.

If all your database access is to the same server, then just create a single connection and pass it to anything that needs access to the connection.  Then the transaction will be application-wide.

```
class ClassThatNeedsDbAccess
{
    protected $connection = NULL;

    protected function doQuery ($query)
    {
        return ($this -> connection -> execute ($query));
    }

    public function __construct (PDO $connection)
    {
        $this -> connection = $connection;
    }
}

class OtherClassThatNeedsDbAccess extends ClassThatNeedsDbAccess
{
}

$myDb = new PDO ('dsn_goes_here');

$obj1 = new ClassThatNeedsDbAccess ($myDb);
$obj2 = new OtherClassThatNeedsDbAccess ($myDb);
```

If you're talking to different database servers, then you probably should wrap all the connections in an object that can coordinate the database activity.  It will be that object's responsibility to track which database connection has a transaction in flight.

Comment: Basically my question meant to ask/target a different approach then this. Maybe I just wanted to cheat a little, and throw OOP out of the window. I'll proceed as you mentioned.

Comment: Good luck with that. That might work in imaginary programs but in practice you will will run into [commands are out of sync](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commands-out-of-sync.html). The question clearly states use of mysqli.

Answer (score 0):

Use one MySQL object - connection for all your business logic... take a look at singleton pattern. You can pass it to constructor or you could use static class method to get mysql object.

Then it's a matter of you where you start end transaction, connection must be the same. Best would be abstract it into some general database access layer.

Comment: thanks, interesting article. So suggestion is just inject database object into?

Comment: Yeah, dependency injection is the way to go.  Injecting the same object into all the dependants will have the same effect as a Singleton, and if you find at some later point that one of the dependants needs a different connection then you just have to give it a different database object.